# Where to put the simplelogger.properties file for slf4j simple logging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, slf4j

To change the logging level of Slf4j simple logger, I was wondering where should I put the simplelogger.properties file in my Eclipse project and how should I refer to it in Eclipse (do I need to setup any arguments?)

Comment: Usually all these config files go into the resource folder.

Comment: I put it there, still didn't work

Comment: What didn't work? What went wrong?

Comment: My simplelogger.properties file includes the line: org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug

I put the file in the resources folder, but still the default debug level is info